# How to add an application to Windows RPC endpoint mapper

Tags: windows, rpc, dcom

Our DCOM application serves up objects on a specific port such as 4162, and the client used to be able to get objects via a moniker specifying a full binding (*e.g.* 10.0.0.15[4162]).

The September 2018 Windows 10 feature update broke this approach, as the endpoint can no longer be specified in the binding in the moniker.  Now the client must assume the endpoint is the well-known RPC endpoint mapper on port 135.  We understand that the endpoint mapper is then responsible for connecting the client to the endpoint associated with the server's application ID, an endpoint which might be statically or randomly assigned.

We have been able to work around this temporarily by bypassing the endpoint mapper using a separate proxy that forwards its port 135 to port 4162 on the server.  Obviously this isn't the "right" way to do it.

We have not been able to find documentation on how to register our application with the endpoint mapper.  We have found a dialog that shows the configuration of DCOM applications in the Component Services dialog but cannot associate a new application ID with an endpoint.

How does one configure the endpoint mapper to direct a client to the proper server binding?